# VS Code does not bring Solution Explorer or Team Explorer like Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I want to access solutions explorer and Team explorer on my VS Code but the option is not there. I know I have to: View > Solution Explorer, or by pressing Ctrl+Alt+L but it does not work.

Can you please help?

Screenshot of my VS Code:
[image: screenshot of my VS Code]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, "solution explorer" and "team explorer" are Visual Studio features / concepts and not Visual Studio Code features / concepts. Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code are not the same.

That said,

- The Explorer panel for VS Code ([image: dark files icon][image: light files icon] / `View: Show Explorer`) is analogous to Visual Studio's Solution Explorer, except that it only supports viewing the files in their layout in the filesystem.

  - There is at least one Solution Explorer extension on the VS Code marketplace: [`fernandoescolar.vscode-solution-explorer`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fernandoescolar.vscode-solution-explorer) <sup><sub>(I have no affiliation with this extension)</sub></sup>.
  - The [C# Dev Kit](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dotnettools) extension has a Solution Explorer feature (run `.NET: Open Solution` in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)).
- The Source Control panel in VS Code ([image: dark source-control icon][image: light source-control icon] / `View: Show Source Control`) is analogous to Visual Studio's Teams Explorer, and you can get more git-related features by instaling related extensions such as [gitlens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens).

Answer (score 1):

If you have the C# Dev Kit installed, Open the Command Palette, and find ".Net: Open Solution".
Then just follow the prompts.